# How to show percentage properly for every culture

Tags: c#, wpf, string, string-formatting

As you know, percentage is written left or right side of number in accordance with language.

For example:

In Turkish : %80 | In English : 80%

with localization doing it is really easy.

It is possible to do it with string format and the demonstration can change when culture is changed?

Any idea or help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say without localization, do you mean globalization (as Leppie says in comments below)?  If so - I'm sorry but this answer basically therefore doesn't answer your question, but comes with a strong advisory **not** to start reinventing lots of wheels.

From [Standard numeric format strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx):

```
decimal percentage = 80.5M;
Console.WriteLine(percentage.ToString("P"));
```

Formats the number as percentage for the current culture.

If it's a particular culture you're after, rather than the current culture, you have two choices - change the current culture (via the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture` members) or you can simply pass the culture as an argument to `ToString()`:

```
decimal percentage = 80.5M;
//English (UK)
Console.WriteLine(percentage.ToString("P", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-GB")));
//Turkish (Turkey)
Console.WriteLine(percentage.ToString("P", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("tr-TR")));
```

Comment: He said doing it without localisation

Comment: Fair point woody - in that case I will update my answer to say that he shouldn't be doing without localisation.  I will take away my downvote though

Comment: it is possible to make this in XAML in Binding ? If it is , could you add the way of it in your answer?

Comment: @Woody: This is not localization, it is globalization.

Comment: @ibrahimyilmaz you'll need to be more specific about this - and that's not the same question as I've answered so you might need to ask another question.  [There is this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591172/wpf-textbox-binding-with-formatting) where in the main body you can see how the OP has approached binding with format - that might help you.