# Caret is on wrong place in WPF custom TextBox control

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, wpf-controls, custom-controls

I'm trying to create a custom control(inherited from TextBox). The main target is Auto-Formatting while user typing. This coontrol only accepts numbers, and auto-completes the input with number grouping separator and decimal separator characters.

Generic.xaml content is the following:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type local:PrecisionTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:PrecisionTextBox}">
                <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=TextContent, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>   
 </Style>
```

And the TextContent property:

```
public string TextContent
    {
        get
        {                
            return this.Value.ToString("N" + Precision);  
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != textContent)
            {
                textContent = value;

                if (textContent.Contains(MultiplierChar))
                {
                    textContent = textContent.Replace(MultiplierChar, "000000");
                }
                try
                {
                    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textContent))
                    {
                        this.Value = Convert.ToDecimal(textContent);
                    }                       
                    
                }
                catch
                {
                    this.Value = 0m;
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

It works great except one thing. The caret... I typed a '0' char and everything is fine until this:

[image: still good]

After then i typed one more '0' number and caret is on wrong place:

[image: bad]

I expect the caret near the next character.I think i know the reason. The input received 3 characters from me(by default it shows 0.00) and the caret is on 3. position. But i want to sync this caret. I was trying to set CaretIndex and SelectionStart properties but none of them worked.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

May be you should use [value converter](http://wpftutorial.net/ValueConverters.html) instead of doing a in-string replace

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this here: [WPF TextBox Binding with Formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4591172/wpf-textbox-binding-with-formatting/19953393#19953393)

That isn't for exactly the same number formatting, it's just for a string of numbers with thousand separators, it doesn't have decimal places, but I'm sure you can change the code to fit your formatting needs.